# Is dyslexia less common among visually impaired?

Tags: developmental-psychology

I couldn't find any information on whether dyslexia is equally prevalent in normally sighted people and among visually impaired people who learned reading and writing through braille?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "equally apparent"? For me, a question on how apparent (visible, etc) dyslexia is in the VI is quite different from a question on prevalence... The first would be a discussion of diagnoses, while the second may be a statistic.

Comment: I edited the question and replaced apparent with prevalent, this should make the question more clear. @mfloren

Comment: Try to add some references to give more credibility to your answer

Answer (score 2):

The term Dyslexia is used to refer to a pattern of learning difficulties
characterized by problems with accurate or fluent word recognition, poor decoding, and poor spelling abilities.

DSM-5 posit: "The learning difficulties are not better accounted for by intellectual disabilities, **uncorrected visual or auditory acuity**, other mental or neurological disorders, psychosocial adversity, lack of proficiency in the language of academic instruction, or inadequate educational instruction"

This is one of the diagnostic criteria for a "Specific learning disorder".
Accordingly, the answer to your question is *no*, because in that case we should talk about another deficit.